# Finding a pair of elements in a list that adds up to a sum using a dictionary

Tags: python

### Context of the problem:

Find Pair with given Sum in the Array.

Given an unsorted list of ints, find a pair with a given sum in it.

EXAMPLE:

list = [8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1]

sum = 10

OUTPUT  = index 0 & 2 (8, 2) or 1 & 4 (7, 3)

### This is what I have so far:

```
def find_pair_dict(ints: [int], sum_: int):

    dict_ = dict()

    # {
    #   element: index
    #   8: 0,
    #   7: 1,
    #   ...
    # }

    output = list()

    for i in range(len(ints)):
        diff = sum_ - ints[i]
        # print(diff)
        if diff not in dict_.keys():
            # int: index
            dict_[ints[i]] = i

        else:
            output.append((dict_[ints[i]], dict_[diff]))

    if not output:
        return "No pairs were found"
    return output
```

I am calling this function with `find_pair_dict([8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1], 10)` and am getting an error that I do not understand.

### The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find_pair_sum.py", line 62, in <module>
    print(find_pair_dict([8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1], 10))
  File "find_pair_sum.py", line 53, in find_pair_dict
    output.append((dict_[ints[i]], dict_[diff]))
KeyError: 2
```

This sounds like the element of `2` cannot be added?

Comment: Yes, because `ints[i]` is `2` and you don't have a `dict_[2]` yet.

Comment: But arent I adding the pair with this `dict_[ints[i]] = i`?

Comment: You only do that `if diff not in dict_.keys()`. What if `ints[i] not in dict_.keys()`?

Answer (score 1):

Almost a one-liner:

```
def find_pairs(ints: [int], sum_: int):
    return {
        tuple(sorted((n, ints.index(sum_-i)))): (i, sum_-i) 
        for n, i in enumerate(ints) if sum_ - i in ints
    }


print(find_pairs([8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1], 10))
```

Result:

```
{(0, 2): (2, 8), (1, 4): (3, 7), (3, 3): (5, 5)}
```

Note: the key to the dictionary is a sorted tuple. A tuple because a list isn't hashable and sorted to avoid both `(0,2)` and `(2,0)` showing up as keys (for example).

The error in your solution occurs because the first time this line is executed:

```
output.append((dict_[ints[i]], dict_[diff]))
```

The value if `dict_` is `{8: 0, 7: 1}` and `ints[i]` is `2`. Since there is no entry for `2` in the dict, you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think there should be three outputs:

- (2,0) = 2,8
- (4,1) = 3,7
- (3,3) = 5,5

The problem has already been succinctly described by @Selcuk. I am suggesting you how to solve that. Many ways. Easiest for me is to use defaultdict from collections.

Below is the code with minimal changes

```py
from collections import defaultdict
def find_pair_dict(ints: [int], sum_: int):

    dict_ = defaultdict(list)

    output = list()

    for i in range(len(ints)):
        diff = sum_ - ints[i]
        dict_[ints[i]] = i
        output.append((dict_[ints[i]], dict_[diff]))

    if not output:
        return "No pairs were found"
    return output

print(find_pair_dict([8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1], 10))
```

This prints out the following. I have not filtered for empty matches.

```py
[(0, []), (1, []), (2, 0), (3, 3), (4, 1), (5, [])]
```

Is this what you wanted?